# Godot Problematic CustomStyle, how can fix this?

Tags: game-engine, godot, gdscript

> Godot version: 3.1 STABLE OS/device
>
> including version: WINDOWS/OS

I’m making a movable window in my game, and I’ve used the `popup()` function. The fact is that I want to style it like a terminal, so I have made a custom style (`StyleBoxFlat`). The problem here is that the “title part” of the popup is becoming transparent. How I can fix this?

**Illustration**
[image]

**Solution from post to Godot Github tracker:**
[image]

Comment: I solved asking to Github. This is the solution for those who wants it

[link](https://i.imgur.com/r6QPFL9.png)

Comment: Why not creating an answer and mark it as resolved yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just Added the solution in the first post.